# AWS file upload with loopback: Failed to create a multipart upload on S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, loopbackjs

Trying to upload multiple image files to `AWS` using `loopback-component-storage`

Here are the methods :

```
 Game.add = function(ctx,options,cb)
        {
               var status = ctx.req.query.status,
                defaultLangCode = ctx.req.query.defaultLangCode,
                nameEn = ctx.req.query.nameEn;

            var rec = new Object();
            rec.parentHouseId = houseId;
            rec.status = status;
            rec.defaultLangCode = defaultLangCode;
            rec.nameEn = nameEn;

            if(!options) options = {forceIframeTransport : true};
            ctx.req.params.container = 'common';
            Game.app.models.container.upload(ctx.req,ctx.result,options,function (err,fileObj) {
                if(err) {
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    var fileInfo = fileObj.files.file[0];
                    console.log(fileInfo);
                }
            });
        };
```

AND

```
Game.remoteMethod(
        'add',
        {
            http:{path: '/add', verb: 'post', status: 200, errorStatus: 400},
            accepts: [
                { arg: 'ctx', type: 'object', http: { source:'context' } },
                { arg: 'options', type: 'object', http:{ source: 'query'} }
            ],
            returns: {
                arg: 'fileObject', type: 'object', root: true
            }
        }
    );
```

I am trying to upload two image files there. Posting data/image produces this error twice:

> Failed to create a multipart upload on S3: {"message":"Access
>   Denied","stack":"AccessDenied: Access Denied\n    at
>   Request.extractError
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:538:35)\n    at
>   Request.callListeners
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)\n
>   at Request.emit
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)\n
>   at Request.emit
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:668:14)\n    at
>   Request.transition
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)\n    at
>   AcceptorStateMachine.runTo
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)\n    at
>   /vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10\n    at
>   Request.
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)\n    at
>   Request.
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:670:12)\n    at
>   Request.callListeners
>   (/vagrant/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)","code":"AccessDenied","region":null,"time":"2016-08-24T19:43:28.415Z","requestId":"2802978376D53185","extendedRequestId":"LhRlXP6H2EQo8M0ECUlL8js4W9CP99h5fvsSHjVSs3mhB9OupvWpz7UdB1HhN0Ntxf6sFLYoHdk=","statusCode":403,"retryable":false,"retryDelay":44.73750370088965}

Second one is of-course different.

I tried using empty `options` object without luck.

Any kind of advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Tried working with different key/key id , same result. And how do I get the uploaded file's url? That of-course after I can successfully upload images :p

Comment: Are you sure your AWS key is correct? Can you upload using another client like postman?

Comment: Yes, keys are correct , if i input a wrong key  this ---> "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling permission for the user in **s3 bucket (permission)policy**.
Have you assigned a role to instance where you are running the code? (If using EC2 as your workstation)

This should have been a comment. But, unfortunately i donot have privileges to comment.